# Trouble getting events working on my site

Tags: javascript, video.js

i am trying to execute a js code on player play/pause. I have tried many solutions found on google but nothing worked. The site is http://www.ihousing.cz .

The code i tried:

```
var myFunc = function(){
  var VideoJS = this;
  jQuery('.nivo-slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
  };
VideoJS.addEvent("play", myFunc);
```

is returning me TypeError: elem.addEventListener is not a function...

What am i missing here?
Thank you for any help

Comment: I didn't see this code in your web page.  The CSS class nivo-slider is only on a a <div> and it doesn't have a data attribute.  Your <video> tag has an ID of 'video-142-video', did you mean to target this and not ".nivo-slider"?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the event handler on the player's ready function.

```
var onPlay = function(){
  //do something on play
};

_V_("your-video-id").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.addEvent("play", onPlay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that i need to get a variable for the player, not just call VideoJS (it expects DOM object as the first param)... So right code should be:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("video-142-video");
var myFunc = function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  jQuery('.nivo-slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
  };
myPlayer.addEvent("play", myFunc);
```

Your code also works...

Thanks everyone involved :D